# In the fantasy movie "Unbreakable" what are the three disasters?

Tags: unbreakable-trilogy, unbreakable

In the fantasy movie *Unbreakable*, which I watched some time ago when they aired it on the TV in France, three disasters are mentioned.

One is the train accident which starts the movie.

Another one is an arson in a hotel, which causes many casualties.

> I do remember the final scene where David, shaking hands with Elijah, has a vision on how the latter learned about the hotel vulnerability, discussing in a bar with an expert on fire safety requirements, who knew they were not implemented in that hotel.

I cannot remember what the third disaster is.

> And also, I'd like to know the details of the vision David had about Elijah causing that disaster when they shake hands.

I was unable to find this information on the web, and I do not have pay TV, so I cannot watch it until they air it again.

Comment: Details are fuzzy, which is why this isn't an answer, but when David shakes Elijah's hand David sees that Elijah set up the train crash, the hotel fire and a plane crash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [original script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/unbreakable.html)

> **ELIJAH:** *There have been **three major disasters** in this city over the last four years. I've followed each one of them... **A Seven-three-seven crashes on take off**. One hundred and seventy-two die. No survivors... **A hotel fire downtown**. Two hundred and eleven die. No survivors... **And an Amtrak train derails seven and half miles outside of the city**. One hundred and thirty one die. One survivor. He is unharmed.*
> (beat) *I've spoken with your husband about his survival. I suggested a rather unbelievable explanation. Since then, I've come to believe, that my explanation, however unbelievable, is in fact, true.*

His vision (when he touches Elijah's arm) is fair confirmation that he caused all of these accidents;

> FLASHCUT: AN AIRPORT GATE. ELIJAH IS STANDING AT THE WINDOW LOOKING OUT ONTO THE AIRFIELD. HE'S CRYING.
> SIRENS START SOUNDING THROUGHOUT THE AIRPORT.
> WAITING PASSENGERS START GETTING UP AND MOVING TO THE WINDOWS.
>
> **MAN:** *What's going on?*
>
> Elijah speaks to no one in particular as he stares out the window with tortured eyes.
>
> **ELIJAH:** *A plane just crashed.*
>
> CUT TO:
> FLASH CUT: ELIJAH AND AN ELDERLY MAN IN A UNIFORM ARE SEATED IN A HOTEL BAR.
>
> **ELDERLY MAN:** *I've worked here twenty-five years. I know all its secrets.*
>
> **ELIJAH:** *Secrets?*
>
> **ELDERLY MAN** (whispers) *Like if there was ever a fire on floors one, two, or three... Everyone in this hotel would be burned alive.*
>
> ELIJAH LOOKS UP FROM HIS DRINK.
>
> CUT TO:
> FLASHCUT: ELIJAH LEAVES THE ENGINEERING ROOM OF AN AMTRAK TRAIN. HE PASSES THE ENGINEER WHO HAS JUST ARRIVED WITH COFFEE.
>
> **ENGINEER:** *Passengers aren't allowed in there.*
>
> Elijah doesn't answer and doesn't turn around as he exits train 177.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I knew it had to be a flashcut, but I forgot the airport scene.

Comment: The talk of major disasters *in this city* makes you wonder: what made Elijah think that, even if his unbreakable counterpart existed, that they would necessarily show up near him?

Comment: @MasonWheeler Because it is another common narrative element in comic books(And many other stories): The villain creates the hero that becomes his nemesis. Elijah believed not just that his opposite existed, but also that he(As the villain) would be the one to make them a hero.

Comment: @MasonWheeler From the news clips on Elijah's wall, he's been doing this for a long time and has a lot more disasters than three to his credit.  Authorities found evidence of three, this may be the three most recent.

Comment: @DarkMatter - I would assume he's been extensively researching disasters from around the country but just got impatient about how few there were